# Put additional column in between columns of the standard app

Tags: sapui5

I'm extending HCMFAB_EMP_LKP. No matter the column index I set it's not affecting the column's position in the table.

[image: screenshot]

`<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <!-- This extension point can be used to add fields to columns -->
    <!--<core:Fragment xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" id="searchResultTableColumns_clone" fragmentName="hcm.fab.employeelookup.view.fragment.EmployeeTableColumns" type="XML"/> -->
    <Column>
        <Text text="HELLO"/>
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "HELLO", "columnIndex" : "1"}'/>
        </customData>
    </Column>
</core:FragmentDefinition>`

What could be wrong in my implementation?
What does 'p13nData' stand for?
Is it right that the 'columnKey' needs to match the column header text or is this key defined somewhere else?
Please note the (slight) difference in style between the header text of the standard column and the custom one. How can I address this in the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table control used in SearchResultList.view.xml is sap.m.Table the p13nData which you tried to use (where have you found this example?) is supported in sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable -> https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/7.40.19/en-US/bed8274140d04fc0b9bcb2db42d8bac2.html

I think you need a view replacement if you want to get your extension in between the existing columns.

I think p13nData stands for Personalization Data.